# Trouble running app from Eclipse after ICS update

Tags: android, eclipse

Ever since my phone got updated to ICS about a month ago (HTC Design on Sprint) whenever I try to run my app from eclipse about 80% of the time it fails. No error, just doesn't run. I get this in the console:

```
[2012-09-21 17:29:59 - GetAClue] ------------------------------
[2012-09-21 17:29:59 - GetAClue] Android Launch!
[2012-09-21 17:29:59 - GetAClue] adb is running normally.
[2012-09-21 17:29:59 - GetAClue] Performing com.badbob.app.getaclue.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-09-21 17:30:01 - GetAClue] Uploading GetAClue.apk onto device 'HT1CHMB00902'
[2012-09-21 17:30:01 - GetAClue] Installing GetAClue.apk...
[2012-09-21 17:30:15 - GetAClue] Success!
[2012-09-21 17:30:15 - GetAClue] Starting activity com.badbob.app.getaclue.MainActivity on device HT1CHMB00902
```

But it stops there and doesn't give me one of these like it should:

```
[2012-09-21 17:26:28 - GetAClue] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.badbob.app.getaclue/.MainActivity }
```

If I keep trying eventually it will run. I also notice that when it fails the processor on my phone is thrashed for a good minute or two. Can't tell what process is thrashing it though.

I have 2 older Droid X's that I don't have this problem with. I also have two dev computers and it happens on both of them with the HTC so it seems to be something up with my phone, or ICS.

Anyone else experiencing this?